# How can I through the OnModelCreating method create foreign keys dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

On my EF6 model I have created certain base classes that contain properties/columns that I want to be inherited across several entities.

Here is a simple example of the concept:

```
public class Replaceable 
{
    [Column("REPLACING")]
    public int Replacing { get; set; }
}

[Table("PARTS")]
public class Part : Replaceable
{
    [Column("ID"), Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("PART_NUMBER")]
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
}
```

So the REPLACING property & column will be inherited to Part-class/PARTS-table.

The REPLACING column is supposed to point towards an ID in the same table. For example if you replace a part you want to keep track of what replaced what.

What I want to do (if possible) through `OnModelCreating` is:

- Get all entities that inherit from Replaceable.
- Mark the column REPLACING as a foreign key and point it to the entity's Primary Key (PART_ID, COMPONENT_ID etc).

The trick here is how to get the name of the ID column of each entity's table since all of them are not called ID but PART_ID, COMPONENT_ID etc.

Is this even possible? An alternative practice is also welcome.

Comment: Maybe create your own attribute and add it to the property you want to use, then use reflection to pull it out?

Comment: @DavidG: Ok that is an option. I have done something similar for setting the decimal precision. Could you setup an example where after getting the attribute you pull out the primary key of each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a base configuration class:

```
public abstract class ReplaceableConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
    where T : Replaceable
{
    public ReplaceableConfiguration()
    {
        this.Property(r => r.Replacing).HasColumnName(typeof(T).Name + "_ID");
    }
}
```

And derive as many concrete classes as you want.

```
public class PartConfiguration : ReplaceableConfiguration<Part>
{ }

public class ComponentConfiguration : ReplaceableConfiguration<Component>
{ }
```

I tried this with just two classes:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PartConfiguration());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ComponentConfiguration());
```

Which gave me this DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PARTS] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [PART_NUMBER] [nvarchar](max),
    [Part_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.PARTS] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COMPONENTS] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [COMPONENT_NUMBER] [nvarchar](max),
    [Component_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.COMPONENTS] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
```